# Terminate application context creation in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am creating my Flask app using an [Application Factory](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/appfactories/) (without calling a main function):

```py
def create_app(test_config=None):

    # create and configure the app
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)

    # read the configuration
    if test_config is None:
        # ensure that instance path and config file exists
        if not os.path.exists(app.instance_path + os.pathsep + "config.py"):
            print("Instance path with config.py file is missing.")
            sys.exit(os.EX_NOINPUT)
```

...and would like to gently terminate the application context whenever some check for a startup precondition (e.g., availability of a config file) fails.

What is the correct way to handle this? `sys.exit` certainly not, because it does not stop the application context from being created.

Comment: is just raising a `FileNotFoundError` sufficient? Do you just want the whole application to crash?

Comment: some form of gentle shutdown if conditions are not met would be desirable